# Unable to modify timezone when creating date from datetime

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, lubridate

I ran into an interesting issue today when trying to create a date column from a datetime column and not being able to retain the right timezone. The question is, in the example below, why does it not seem possible to modify the timezone of the "date" column?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)

# create a short datetime sequence
df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(ymd_hm("2020-1-1 0:00"), ymd_hm("2020-1-3 12:00"), by = "hour"))

# check the timezone -- it is UTC
tz(df$datetime)

# convert to PST
df$datetime <- force_tz(df$datetime, "US/Pacific")

# confirm -- OK
tz(df$datetime) # [1] "US/Pacific"

# now create a date column based on the datetime column
df$date <- as.Date(df$datetime)

# might think it would be PST, but it's UTC
tz(df$date)

# attempt to change it manually to PST
df$date <- force_tz(df$date, tz="US/Pacific")

# doesn't work
tz(df$date) # [1] "UTC"

# seems we're stuck -- the date column reflects UTC and changes to January 2nd at 4PM on 1/1
# in the datetime column
df[15:20,]
```

The output is technically correct (i.e., 8 hour offset) but it seems terribly confusing to have two different timezones across the two columns.

```
              datetime       date
15 2020-01-01 14:00:00 2020-01-01
16 2020-01-01 15:00:00 2020-01-01
17 2020-01-01 16:00:00 2020-01-02
18 2020-01-01 17:00:00 2020-01-02
19 2020-01-01 18:00:00 2020-01-02
20 2020-01-01 19:00:00 2020-01-02
```

Comment: Potentially check your R/lubridate versions, because `force_tz` works for me (lubridate 1.7.9, R 4.0.2).

Comment: Thanks @heds1, the update to 1.7.9 does appear to fix the nominal timezone for the 'date' column but then then output is identical to the output in the example above, where the date still advances to Jan. 2nd at 4PM in the datetime column. Is this also what you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's nasty.  I can't explain why the `tz` argument doesn't work as you've tried it.  It's what I would have done.  After a little experimentation, I found that replacing

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$datetime)
```

with

```
df$date <- with_tz(date(df$datetime), tz="US/Pacific")
```

gives the desired result:

```
tz(df$date)
[1] "US/Pacific"
```

[`df$date <- with_tz(as.Date(df$datetime), tz="US/Pacific")` also works.]

@heds1:  `force_tz` fails for me, as for OP.  Selected `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
lubridate_1.7.4
```

**Update**

No one has been sufficiently clear in their comments to be sure *exactly* what code is being run to generate each set of results.  But I think I may have the source of the confusion:  it's the `df$date <- force_tz(df$date, tz="US/Pacific")`.

From the [online doc](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/force_tz.html) for `force_tz`: "`force_tz` returns the date-time that has the same clock time as input time, but in the new time zone", whereas the [same sentence](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/with_tz.html) for `with_tz` reads "`with_tz` returns a date-time as it would appear in a different time zone".

The difference is subtle but important: `force_tz` simply replaces the value of the time zone field leaving the clock time unaffected, whereas `with_tz` maps the clock time to the corresponding clock time in the new time zone at the same instant.

Reworking OP's code slightly for clarity:

```
# create a short datetime sequence
df <- data.frame(utc_datetime = seq(ymd_hm("2020-1-1 0:00"), ymd_hm("2020-1-3 12:00"), by = "hour"))
# check the timezone -- it is UTC
tz(df$utc_datetime)
[1] "UTC"
# convert to PST
df$pst_datetime <- with_tz(df$utc_datetime, tz="US/Pacific")
# confirm -- OK
tz(df$pst_datetime) # [1] "US/Pacific"
[1] "US/Pacific"
# Convert UTC datetime to Date
df$utc_date <- with_tz(date(df$utc_datetime))
tz(df$utc_date)
[1] "UTC"
# Convert PST datetime to Date
df$pst_date <- with_tz(date(df$pst_datetime), tz="US/Pacific")
tz(df$pst_date)
[1] "US/Pacific"
# List to show behaviour around midnight for both UTC and PST
df[22:35,]
          utc_datetime        pst_datetime   utc_date   pst_date
22 2020-01-01 21:00:00 2020-01-01 13:00:00 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
23 2020-01-01 22:00:00 2020-01-01 14:00:00 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
24 2020-01-01 23:00:00 2020-01-01 15:00:00 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
25 2020-01-02 00:00:00 2020-01-01 16:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
26 2020-01-02 01:00:00 2020-01-01 17:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
27 2020-01-02 02:00:00 2020-01-01 18:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
28 2020-01-02 03:00:00 2020-01-01 19:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
29 2020-01-02 04:00:00 2020-01-01 20:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
30 2020-01-02 05:00:00 2020-01-01 21:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
31 2020-01-02 06:00:00 2020-01-01 22:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
32 2020-01-02 07:00:00 2020-01-01 23:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
33 2020-01-02 08:00:00 2020-01-02 00:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-02
34 2020-01-02 09:00:00 2020-01-02 01:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-02
35 2020-01-02 10:00:00 2020-01-02 02:00:00 2020-01-02 2020-01-02
```

Comment: Thanks @Limey. After updating to lubridate 1.7.9, and using your suggestion for 'df$date <- with_tz(date(df$datetime), tz="US/Pacific")', I'm able to get the right timezone for the 'date' column, but if you look at the results in the final step, it is '2019-12-31 16:00:00' for the entire time that the datetime column is Jan. 1. Wondering if this means I just need to create the date column before modifying the timezone of the datetime column in the first place?

Comment: R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it does identify the mechanism affecting the final product and provides a functional workaround. However, I'm still convinced that there's something "off" with how 'lubridate' treats these columns with different timezones. If you go back and look at my initial reprex, you'll see that my use of 'force_tz' is consistent with my objectives. In reality, the initial timeseries is something that I read in from a file and is already in PST. Hence my use of 'force_tz'. It is possible to create new columns with the right timezone, but now they are 7-8 hours off.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, I don't believe there is a way to convert the 'datetime' column to PST first, and then create a date column (based on datetime in PST) that has the correct timezone AND gives the right results on a row-by-row basis. Instead, if I first create both columns in UTC, then convert both to PST, it seems to work. Granted I'm still mystified why the previous approach seems to fail if you look at the final result (even if the timezone of the date column appears to be correct).

```
library(lubridate)

# create a short datetime sequence
df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(ymd_hm("2020-1-1 0:00"), ymd_hm("2020-1-3 12:00"), by = "hour"))

# check the timezone on datetime -- it is UTC
tz(df$datetime)

# now create a date column based on the datetime column in UTC
df$date <- as.Date(df$datetime)

# check date timezone -- also UTC
tz(df$date)

# now manually change both
df$datetime <- force_tz(df$datetime, tz="US/Pacific")
df$date <- force_tz(df$date, tz="US/Pacific")

# check -- both correctly register 'US/Pacific'
tz(df$datetime)
tz(df$date)

# now the two columns seem to match up
df[1:30,]
```

Here are the results -- note the dates do match up to the datetimes.

```
              datetime       date
1  2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01
2  2020-01-01 01:00:00 2020-01-01
3  2020-01-01 02:00:00 2020-01-01
4  2020-01-01 03:00:00 2020-01-01
5  2020-01-01 04:00:00 2020-01-01
6  2020-01-01 05:00:00 2020-01-01
7  2020-01-01 06:00:00 2020-01-01
8  2020-01-01 07:00:00 2020-01-01
9  2020-01-01 08:00:00 2020-01-01
10 2020-01-01 09:00:00 2020-01-01
11 2020-01-01 10:00:00 2020-01-01
12 2020-01-01 11:00:00 2020-01-01
13 2020-01-01 12:00:00 2020-01-01
14 2020-01-01 13:00:00 2020-01-01
15 2020-01-01 14:00:00 2020-01-01
16 2020-01-01 15:00:00 2020-01-01
17 2020-01-01 16:00:00 2020-01-01
18 2020-01-01 17:00:00 2020-01-01
19 2020-01-01 18:00:00 2020-01-01
20 2020-01-01 19:00:00 2020-01-01
21 2020-01-01 20:00:00 2020-01-01
22 2020-01-01 21:00:00 2020-01-01
23 2020-01-01 22:00:00 2020-01-01
24 2020-01-01 23:00:00 2020-01-01
25 2020-01-02 00:00:00 2020-01-02
26 2020-01-02 01:00:00 2020-01-02
27 2020-01-02 02:00:00 2020-01-02
28 2020-01-02 03:00:00 2020-01-02
29 2020-01-02 04:00:00 2020-01-02
30 2020-01-02 05:00:00 2020-01-02
```

Here is the session info:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
```